# Selenium python click on button dont work

Tags: python, selenium, web

[]  In the photo you can see two buttons SING UP which is where the web opens by default as soon as you load it and the one I want to click LOGIN, the site is full of Java and I know that solving this problem will help me later, hopefully someone can help me, I would appreciate it a million [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wVux.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply click the a href tag with the LOGIN text.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("a[text()='LOGIN']").click()
```